# Getting views to flip without flipping labels

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel

My issue is that when I flip my UIView, it obviously flips the label inside of it. Is there any way I can counter that somehow? The label inside of it is created programmatically when I tap somewhere on the UIView(where it is created). So is there any way I can flip the UIView without or countering the flipping of the label that has been added as a subview to the UIView?
Code is below:
To help you understand it, I have two UIViews. One is a huge block (bottomCourt)
The other one is added as a subView to the huge block. It is called "dot". Lastly, I create a label and add it as a subview to dot.
When I flip the bottomCourt(big block) it flips everything inside of it. Yes, I need the dot to be flipped) but I need the label to stay right side up.

The following code is being put in the TouchesBegan part of my view.

```
            var dot = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: locationB.x, y: locationB.y, width: 10, height: 10))
             dot.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            dot.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
            self.bottomCourt.addSubview(dot)

            shot++
            var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10))
            label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            label.text = "\(shot)"
            label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(7)
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            dot.addSubview(label)
```

So because I can't really control the dots since I add them as a new variable every time I tap, once again, how to I flip everything written in the code besides the "label"?

Comment: You want the label to be animated along with the dot, but for the label's text to end up readable?

Answer (score 0):

try this ,create a containerView,bottomCourt on container,dot on bottomCourt,label on containerView ,then flip the bottomCourt

Comment: It's not as easy as that

Comment: I made a gif ,hope it would be helpful,code also in this repo [link](https://github.com/jack903652/gif/blob/master/2016-01-28%2015_18_44.gif)